# An example of totally ordered field with cardinality larger than continuum.

Tags: field-theory, set-theory

Is there any totally ordered field with cardinality larger than the continuum? If such field exist, please give an example (an simple one if possible).

Comment: The [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) are an ordered field that is a proper class, so it’s too big even to have a cardinality.

Comment: re Brian M. Scott: What if I also require it to be a set?

Comment: See the earlier question.